# call command in batch file - global local variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get my head around the problems with call command and in particular when a batch call a second batch and if the variables are global or local.

Two questions:

[First question]
In the example below call command doesn’t work and I think because there are setlocal\endlocal in the second.bat and so variables are not visible in the environment of first.bat. Right? 
(if I execute second.bat without setlocal\endlocal first.bat works).

[Second question]
when I run second.bat without setlocal\endlocal how can I test\check\trace if variables are or aren’t global?

thanks for your help.
giac

first.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
…
call C:\WINDOWS\system32\second.bat variable_01 variable_02
…
echo variables (worked by second.bat)
……
endlocal
@echo on
```

second.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
…
something that works variables
…
endlocal
@echo on
```

Comment: 1/ Yes 2/ `if not defined %variable% echo %variable is not defined`

Comment: @DavidPostill, you must not place surrounding `%`-signs in `if exist variable`; otherwise, the content of `%variable%` is treated as the variable name to check for existence...

Comment: @aschipfl Of course, silly mistake.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but i don't think you need the `setlocal` for what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can pass variables back to first.bat when you (re-)set them on the same line following the endlocal command. Otherwisse called batches share the same environment while programs inherit a copy of the environment.